# Is there a Unix/Linux platform equivalent of Telligent Community (formerly Community Server)?

Tags: untagged

[Telligent Community](http://telligent.com/products/telligent_community/) combines blogs, wikis, forums, and file-sharing capabilities into a single product with single sign-on, using all Microsoft technologies.  Is there an equivalent offering that runs on Unix/Linux?  Or would I have to pick and choose individual product offerings and figure out another option for single sign-on across them?  Are there plug-ins for something like WordPress or MovableType that might add the necessary functionality?

A friend of mine is looking to add a "members-only" area to her company's website, and since they're hosted on Dreamhost (and can't afford [StackExchange pricing](http://stackexchange.com/pricing) yet), I'm trying to find other options for them.

Comment: Crossposted at: http://superuser.com/questions/128780/is-there-a-unix-linux-platform-equivalent-to-telligent-community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of commercial platforms which compete in this space, but I think you'll find they're all pretty spendy.

My recommendation would be to check out Drupal (http://drupal.org)

Based on the information in your question, I think that platform would likely meet your needs. It also has a pretty vibrant development community, so there are plenty of plug-ins available to extend its capabilities.